# How prevent fetch request before auth token is received in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, token, http-status-code-401

I have a separate fetch request function that logins user and saves auth token to localStorage, then my data request fetch should be send with that saved token bearer, but data fetch doesn't wait for token and receives Unauthorized access code.

My data request fetch looks like this :

```
// to check for fetch err

function findErr(response) {
    try {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 299) {
            return response.json();
        } else if (response.status === 401) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        } else if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        } else {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.data;
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("caught error: ", error);
    }
}



const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));

// actual fetch request

export async function getData() {
    const url = `${URL}/data`;

    var obj = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + `${token}`,
        },
    };

    const data = await fetch(url, obj)
        .then((response) => findErr(response))
    
        .then((result) => {
            return result.data;
        });

    return data;
}
```

My fetch requests are in a different js file, I'm importing them in my components like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


function getInfo() {

const [info, setInfo] = useState()

const importGetDataFunc = async () => {
        const data = await getData();

        setInfo(data);
    };

useEffect(() => {
        importGetDataFunc();
    
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default getInfo
```

Now when I go to the getInfo component after login at first fetch request returns 401, but after I refresh the page fetch request goes with token bearer and data gets returned. My problem is that I don't know how to make getData() fetch request to wait until it gets token from localStorage or retry fetch request on 401 code. I tried to implement if statement like this

```
useEffect(() => {

if(token){
        importGetDataFunc();
}
    }, []);
```

where useEffect would check if token is in localStorage and only then fire fetch request, but it didn't work. Any help on how I can handle this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually helped me is to make a function to check for a token inside get fetch request, like this:

```
export const findToken = () => {
    const token =localStorage.getItem("token") 

    return token;
};
export async function getData(token) {
    const url = `${URL}/data`;

    var obj = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + `${findToken()}`,
        },
    };

    const data = await fetch(url, obj)
        .then((response) => findErr(response))
    
        .then((result) => {
            return result.data;
        });

    return data;
}
```

Comment: This will have certain performance bottlenecks. You'll be synchronously retrieving the token from localStorage everytime. I suggest writing a `localStorage` hook which uses lazy initialisation (token is only fetched at the first render) and use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. You need to add `token` as a dependency to your `useEffect`. Also, you need to move your token fetching logic into your component.

Something like this should work:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


function getInfo() {

const [info, setInfo] = useState()
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));

const importGetDataFunc = async () => {
        const data = await getData();

        setInfo(data);
    };

useEffect(() => {
        if(token) {
           importGetDataFunc(token);
        }
    
    }, [token]);

    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default getInfo
```

You can also modify your `importGetDataFunc` to receive the token as a parameter.

```
const importGetDataFunc = async (token) => {
        const data = await getData(token);

        setInfo(data);
    };
```

```
export async function getData(token) {
    const url = `${URL}/data`;

    var obj = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + `${token}`,
        },
    };

    const data = await fetch(url, obj)
        .then((response) => findErr(response))
    
        .then((result) => {
            return result.data;
        });

    return data;
}
```

Comment: I modified code like this: ``` useEffect(() => {
        if(token) {
           importGetDataFunc(token);
        }
    
    }, [token]); ``` and I'm checking for token in my component, it still doesn't work.  Fetch still goes without token bearer on 1st page load.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't because url won't work, it's a local server. I'm trying to implement retry fetch on 401 status code, if you have any suggestions how could I do that in findErr fucntion could you please share? Thank you.

Comment: Can you check to see what is the value of `token`? Use a `console.log` inside the `useEffect`.\

Comment: console.log(token) returns saved token value correctly but still on 1st load it gives 401.

Comment: Is it possible that your token might be expired? Also check if your `importGetData` receives the correct token

Comment: @new_reactjs Please consider closing the question if your issue has been resolved. Mark the answer as correct. Otherwise, we can continue this conversation in the chat